# Webdesign: How to deal with window resizing?

Tags: css, layout, window, html

Can somebody please tell me the best way to deal with different window sizes and with a user resizing the window when creating a webpage.

Because I always find myself creating layouts with html, css, etc. and at first everything look perfect. But as soon as I increase or decrease the size of the browser window everything falls apart.

Also it would be great if anybody could point me to some sort of guide or anything similar.

Thanks it advance! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For detection, you may want to use css media queries (in which case you may want to to use https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond Respond.js's shim for older browsers, to add fuller cross browser support), and target certain screen widths.  http://html5boilerplate.com and it's default css: http://html5boilerplate.com/css/style.css has a great default css set for exactly that type of media query.

Another approach is to give a fixed minimum and maximum widths to the outer container of the page.  For example:

```
body{text-align:center;} 
#outer-container{text-align:left;margin:0 auto 0; width:98%;max-width:900px;min-width:760px;}
```

that way you can grow and shrink it and see how it looks within a certain range and know that other viewing windows are going to see that plus a horizontal scroll bar at worst for small viewing.

In general, just using the html5boilerplate as a starting base is a great approach, it's an excellent piece of work.